# Vue.js how to for-loop and style an objects properties within an array?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, web, vue.js

I'm currently working with Vue.JS and I've been having some trouble outputting some data with the v-for loop.

My goal is to have a 'base' item repeat itself but contain unique information, please see the image below for reference.
[image]

So far, I've somewhat go this working. I'm unsure if this is the "best" or most efficient/optimal way to do it, so I was hoping someone could give me some advice on it.

```
<template>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="value in items">
        {{ value.itemname }}
        {{ value.itemprice }}
        {{ value.bInStock }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
        items: [
          {
            itemquality: "Brand new",
            itemname: "Test Item Name",
            itemprice: "$426.32",
            bInStock: false
          },
          {
            itemquality: "Used",
            itemname: "Test Item Name 2",
            itemprice: "$126.32",
            bInStock: true
          }
        ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The next issue I ran into is binding a class to a value based on the data in the 'items' array.
If I wasn't to use an array, and instead just have a single object, I could do;

```
  <li v-for="(value, key) in myArrayOfObjects">
     <div :class="{'my-price-class': key === 'price'}"> {{value}}</div>
  </li>
```

However, because I have an array, the 'key' that gets returned is just the array index. Is there any way I can use the object properties like; 'itemname' as the key while it's inside an array?

Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
<li v-for="item in array">
  <div class="price-div">{{ item.price }}</div>
</li>
```

Back to the Question, to achieve the behavior you mentioned, just iterate again over the item (the object) to get the key values

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      myArr: [{
        key1: 'some key value 1',
        key2: 'some key value 2',
        redKey: 'red key value',
        key4: 'some key value 3'
      }]
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(value in myArr">
    <div v-for="(v, k) in value">
      <p :class="{red: k === 'redKey'}">
        {{ k }} : {{ v }}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. However a problem I run into now is that I can't access the properties with the dot operator when inside the 2nd for loop.

For example I can't do; {{ v.name }}

Comment: Also if further clarification is needed for what I mean, or an example is needed, please let me know and I will post some sample code or give a visual representation of what I mean. :)

Comment: because v.name does not exist, v it's already the value of the key (k) name.

Comment: Hey, I'm afraid I'm unsure what you mean.
If I just do;
`{{ item }}` it outputs all properties in the array.
If I do anything else like;
`item.name', `key.name`, etc... it doesn't work.

Here is a JSFiddle of the best I've managed to get it. Perhaps you could elaborate a bit more on what you said previously with my example.
https://jsfiddle.net/50wL7mdz/155729/

Thanks.

Comment: it does not work because `item` is just the plain value (v) of the object indexed on the key (k), so if `obj.name = 'foo'`, then `obj[k] = 'foo'`, and `v = 'foo'`, take a look at the for-in documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement

Comment: Apologies but I'm just not getting it.
obj[k] does NOT = 'foo' but in fact = the first character of the property.
From your example above; `v[0] = s` (first character of the value at that index) as shown in this fiddle here.
https://jsfiddle.net/duh74vn5

Comment: Thanks. That clears that up, but I'm still unsure how this helps for what I want to do.
If I want to access an objects properties individually like;
`<p>{{ v.key1 }}}</p>`
`<p>{{ v.key2 }}}</p>`
`<p>{{ v.key4 }}}</p>`
etc...

Using {{ value[key] }} still only prints out all properties in the object together rather than separately.

Comment: just use `value` from first loop to do things like `{{ value.name }}`, and use the `k` to add the desired classes